# Specialization of constrained, recursive generic functions

Tags: haskell, generics, optimization

I've been working on adding support for generic deriving to `linear-base`, building on some work started by Sjoerd Visscher. Things generally work out about as well as can be expected for performance with generics, but I'm running into an issue with recursive types (like lists) that I don't know what to do about. The simplest example of this is the `Consumable` class. Don't be thrown by the linear type stuff if you're not familiar with it; it's pretty much irrelevant here. We have

```hs
class Consumable a where
  -- Read this as consume :: a -> (), but it's guaranteed to use
  -- its argument exactly once.
  consume :: a %1 -> ()

instance (Generic a, GConsumable (Rep a)) => Consumable (Generically a) where
  consume (Generically x) = genericConsume x

genericConsume :: (Generic a, GConsumable (Rep a)) => a %1 -> ()
genericConsume = gconsume . from
{-# INLINEABLE genericConsume #-}

-- | A class for generic representations that can be consumed.
class GConsumable f where
  gconsume :: f p %1 -> ()

instance GConsumable U1 where
  gconsume U1 = ()
  {-# INLINE gconsume #-}

instance (GConsumable f, GConsumable g) => GConsumable (f :+: g) where
  gconsume (L1 a) = gconsume a
  gconsume (R1 a) = gconsume a
  {-# INLINE gconsume #-}

instance (GConsumable f, GConsumable g) => GConsumable (f :*: g) where
  gconsume (a :*: b) = gconsume a `seqUnit` gconsume b
  {-# INLINE gconsume #-}

instance Consumable c => GConsumable (K1 i c) where
  gconsume (K1 c) = consume c
  {-# INLINE gconsume #-}

instance GConsumable f => GConsumable (M1 i t f) where
  gconsume (M1 a) = gconsume a
  {-# INLINE gconsume #-}

-- There are instances for more generic representations, but
-- they're not relevant to the question
```

If we define

```hs
deriving via
  Generically [a]
  instance
    Consumable a => Consumable [a]
```

then we get the following Core (`-ddump-simpl -dsuppress-coercions -dsuppress-type-applications`):

```
Rec {
-- RHS size: {terms: 15, types: 12, coercions: 2, joins: 0/0}
Data.Unrestricted.Linear.Internal.Consumable.$fConsumableNonEmpty_$cconsume1 [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: forall a. Consumable a => [a] %1 -> ()
[GblId, Arity=2, Str=<LCL(A)><1L>, Unf=OtherCon []]
Data.Unrestricted.Linear.Internal.Consumable.$fConsumableNonEmpty_$cconsume1
  = \ (@a_a6VD)
      ($dConsumable_a6VE :: Consumable a_a6VD)
      (eta_B0 :: [a_a6VD]) ->
      case eta_B0 of {
        [] -> GHC.Tuple.();
        : f1_a7mo f2_a7mp ->
          case ($dConsumable_a6VE `cast` <Co:2>) f1_a7mo of { () ->
          Data.Unrestricted.Linear.Internal.Consumable.$fConsumableNonEmpty_$cconsume1
            $dConsumable_a6VE f2_a7mp
          }
      }
end Rec }
```

See the problem? This is a loop breaker with no unfolding, so it can't specialize to a particular `Consumable a` instance. Ugh. Writing the `Consumable` instance manually, we can avoid this problem with scoped type variables:

```
instance Consumable a => Consumable [a] where
  consume = go
    where
      go :: [a] %1 -> ()
      go [] = ()
      go (x : xs) = consume x `seqUnit` go xs
```

Now we get the much more satisfactory

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 18, types: 16, coercions: 2, joins: 1/1}
Data.Unrestricted.Linear.Internal.Consumable.$fConsumableNonEmpty_$cconsume1
  :: forall a. Consumable a => [a] %1 -> ()
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Str=<LCL(A)><1L>,
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=2,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=False)
         Tmpl= \ (@a_a71g)
                 ($dConsumable_a71h [Occ=OnceL1!] :: Consumable a_a71g)
                 (eta_B0 [Occ=Once1] :: [a_a71g]) ->
                 joinrec {
                   go_s7zZ [Occ=LoopBreakerT[1]] :: [a_a71g] %1 -> ()
                   [LclId[JoinId(1)], Arity=1, Str=<L>, Unf=OtherCon []]
                   go_s7zZ (ds_d7bD [Occ=Once1!] :: [a_a71g])
                     = case ds_d7bD of {
                         [] -> GHC.Tuple.();
                         : x_a59q [Occ=Once1] xs_a59r [Occ=Once1] ->
                           case ($dConsumable_a71h `cast` <Co:2>) x_a59q of { () ->
                           jump go_s7zZ xs_a59r
                           }
                       }; } in
                 jump go_s7zZ eta_B0}]
Data.Unrestricted.Linear.Internal.Consumable.$fConsumableNonEmpty_$cconsume1
  = ....
```

Is there any way to achieve this with generics, or is that a lost cause?

In principle, GHC could lift out the static dictionary argument(s); perhaps this problem is best addressed at the compiler level?

---

I just realized that this problem also affects generic deriving for `NFData`. Ouch!

Comment: Are you working with GHC HEAD? The definition of `genericConsume` does not type check for me on GHC 9.0.2 or GHC 9.2.1 (multiplicity mismatch in the linear types)

Comment: @DavidYoung, I suspect the problem is that I'm using `(.)` from the linear prelude rather than the standard one. Oops... The exact same issue shows up with `NFData`, so you can play with that instead.

Comment: For a harder version of this problem, consider generic deriving of `Foldable`, where there's also a `Monoid` that wants specialization.

Comment: The `Foldable` one is actually harder for a different reason; sorry. We want the passed function to be able to inline.